# Find input fields (with id's) in current table row

Tags: jquery

I have a table with injected rows and inputs with id's. What I want to achieve is to get the current rows input's values in jquery. The button is in the last td of the actual row.

```
$("body").on("click", "button.saveOneToManyRow", function (e) {
    $.each(fields, function (key) {
        log($(this).closest("tr").find("#"+key).val());
    });
});
```

I have to work with id's on the inputs in stead of just iterating over the rows elements. The 'keys' are correctly reflecting the input fields id's but the values are undefined.

Comment: are there multiple elements with same id? can you share a html sample of the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `$.each`, `this` is the current element of the array you're looping over, not the target of the event. You need to save that to another variable first. And since the row doesn't change during the loop, you might as well do that part outside the loop as well.

```
$("body").on("click", "button.saveOneToManyRow", function (e) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $.each(fields, function (key) {
        log(row.find("#"+key).val());
    });
});
```